# No known driver to handle "jdbc:calcite:model=druid/src/test/resources/druid-wiki-model.json

Tags: druid, apache-calcite, sqlline, bigdata

I am trying to run calcite and sqlline with druid. I downloaded the ZIP from calcite downloads website and put it inside the druid folder. When i try to run sqlline command

```
!connect jdbc:calcite:model=druid/src/test/resources/druid-wiki-model.json admin admin
```

from the calcite folder  it throws driver error 
`No known driver to handle "jdbc:calcite:model=druid/src/test/resources/druid-wiki-model.json"`. 
Am i missing some driver or installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that Calcite's JAR file is on SQLline's class path. (Probably the easiest way to do this is to edit `sqlline.sh` or `sqlline.bat`.) SQLline loads all JDBC drivers it finds on its class path.

Comment: Worked ! Thanks.

Comment: @julian, I tried adding the path to 'sqlline' script in the sqlline/bin directory but an still  getting the same error. Can I provide any more info to debug this?